# Specific format Join results on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I have trawled the internet looking for a solution but nothing so far.
Here are 2 sample tables joined on SID/ID

```
SID Name    Attendance  Class
1   abc good    1A
2   xyz bad 1B
3   dsk good    1A
4   uij bad 1B
5   sss bad 1A
6   fff good    1D
7   ccc good    1A


ID  Lesson  Result
1   Read    Pass-67%
1   Write   Pass-89%
1   Sing    Pass-99%
2   Read    Pass-75%
3   Sing    Fail-47%
3   Read    Pass-55%
4   Write   Pass-90%
4   Sing    Fail-10%
```

The results need to be in the following format.
A row showing the student name, followed by rows of the students' results.

If a student does not have any results they will not be included.

```
1,  abc,    good,   1A
1,  Read,   Pass-67%    
1,  Write,  Pass-89%    
1,  Sing,   Pass-99%    
2,  xyz,    bad,    1B
2,  Read,   Pass-75%    
3,  dsk,    good,   1A
3,  Sing,   Fail-47%    
3,  Read,   Pass-55%    
4,  uij,    bad,    1B
4,  Write,  Pass-90%    
4,  Sing,   Fail-10%
```

I attempted using Union to no avail, it is similar to a pivot have not had any luck with that either. Is assume i’m missing a trick here, how can I get this done?

I have included the data if it makes it any easier!

```
CREATE TABLE RESULTS (ID Int, Lesson varchar(12), Result nvarchar(8))
insert into RESULTS (ID, Lesson, Result)
values
(1,'Read', 'Pass-67%'),
(1,'Write', 'Pass-89%'),
(1,'Sing', 'Pass-99%'),
(2,'Read', 'Pass-75%'),
(3,'Sing', 'Fail-47%'),
(3,'Read','Pass-55%'),
(4,'Write', 'Pass-90%'),
(4,'Sing', 'Fail-10%')

CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (ID int, Name varchar(5), Attendance nvarchar(10), 
Class nvarchar (3))

insert into STUDENTS values
(1,'abc','good','1A'),
(2,'xyz','bad','1B'),
(3,'dsk','good','1A'),
(4,'uij','bad','1B'),
(5,'sss','bad','1A'),
(6,'fff','good','1D'),
(7,'ccc','good','1A')
```

Comment: "A row showing the student name, followed by rows of the students' results."  This is not really how SQL works.  Tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  So, "following row" doesn't really make sense.  Although this is possible with a somewhat complex `order by`, I would question why you don't want the student name in every row.

Comment: There is no association (i.e. foreign key) between these two tables. Joining these two tables? Am I missing the point? Or are you just mashing these two tables together?

Comment: Also, you need to provide an example of what you tried so far.

Comment: So you want to interleave the meaning of the 2nd column to be either the name, or the lesson, 3rd column to be attendance or result - it's a very unusual requirement and instinctively seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I agree this is not the best practice. However, I am using another program that only imports data in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` with a few workarounds.

```
;WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT
        S.ID,
        S.Name,
        S.Attendance,
        S.Class,
        IsStudent = 1
    FROM    
        Students AS S
    WHERE
        EXISTS (SELECT 'at least one result' FROM Results AS R WHERE R.ID = S.ID)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ID = R.ID,
        Name = R.Lesson,
        Attendance = R.Result,
        Class = NULL,
        IsStudent = 0
    FROM    
        Results AS R
)
SELECT
    D.ID,
    D.Name,
    D.Attendance,
    D.Class
FROM
    Data AS D
ORDER BY
    ID,
    IsStudent DESC
```

But, as you can see on the final column names, you are mixing different data together which is not a good thing to do.

Comment: Fantastic EzLo this has worked perfectly! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all` :

```
select t.* 
from(select ID, Name, Attendance, class 
     from STUDENTS s 
     where exists (select 1 from RESULTS where id = s.id) union all
     select ID, Lesson, Result, null
     from RESULTS r 
    ) t
order by id, (case when class is not null then 0 else 1 end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply concat those columns and Union

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),id)+' , '+Name+' , '+Attendance 
AS ResultSet        INTO #T FROM dbo.STUDENTS
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ID)+' , '+Lesson+' , '+  Result 
FROM   dbo.RESULTS

SELECT * FROM #T ORDER BY ResultSet

DROP TABLE #T
```